# ACL implementation for databases

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, acl

I'm trying to implement an ACL in my database. I have a database which looks like:

```
SYS_USERS { id, name, .. }
AUTH { au_id, au_name, .. }
USER_GROUPS { sys_users_id, auth_id } // bridge table
```

And say `AUTH` data looks like:

```
au_id    au_name    ...
    1      admin    ...
    2      staff    ...
  ...        ...    ...
```

My question is, how can I structure my query from `php` such that upon login, depending on your authentication level, you are presented different pages?

At the moment I have this, which seems a little off:

```
<?php
// code which verifies session variables etc here

$mysql_hostname = 'localhost';
$mysql_username = '...';
$mysql_password = '...';
$mysql_dbname = '...';

try {
    /* Set up new DB object */
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$mysql_hostname;dbname=$mysql_dbname", $mysql_username, $mysql_password);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    /* authenticate user access level */
    // username = 'blah' for question clarity
    $query = $db->prepare('SELECT au_name FROM auth WHERE au_id = (SELECT auth_id FROM user_groups WHERE sys_users_id = (SELECT id FROM sys_users WHERE username="blah"))');

    // do something with results..

} catch(Exception $exception) {
    $message = 'We are unable to process your request. Please try again later';
}
```

?>

So I guess my questions are:

1. Is the `SELECT` query adequate? Or should I use an `INNER JOIN` to achieve the same results? (Does it matter?)
2. Upon success of the query, how do I show the page depending on the level? For example, if it returned `admin` do I write a function such that

```
if ($result == 'admin') {
      // show admin.php
    } elseif ($result == 'staff') {
      // show staff.php
    } else { ... }
```

But this seems rather 'hard coded', i.e. if we were to extend the system for more `AUTH` roles, we would need to then add in more `IF/ELSEIF` statements to the above.

Anyone able to lead me in the right direction?

Thanks.

**EDIT**
So I was thinking of a new way to do this. I could add two more database tables:

```
PAGES { id, page_name .. }
AUTH_PAGES { au_id, pages_id, .. } // bridge between auth and pages
```

Which then in `pages` I could store `page_name` which would hold the authentication level required to view that page?

For example:
 a page called `admin_page.php` could only be accessed by administrators. Therefore this row in `pages` looks like:

```
id           page_name        
 1      admin_page.php
 2    members_page.php
```

and `auth_pages`:

```
au_id    pages_id
    1           1
    1           2
```

Which is to say the `auth` row `admin` (au_name) has access to `admin_page.php` and `members_page.php`. Then all I would need to do in my `PHP` would be to cross reference the page name with the `id` from `pages` table with `auth_pages` table using `echo basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);`.

Does that make any practical sense?

Comment: implementing ZEND ACL like login mechanism is a bit tricky.. so do you keey the list of pages accessible by different roles in a table?

Comment: Not at the moment, no. Would this be a better route to take? I was planning on simply doing the table lookups using the `IF ELSE` statements from above before redirecting and then verifying again (to prevent users from simply typing `../admin.php` to  get to the admin page) on each page on load via `user_id` session variable which is set on successful login. Thanks.

Comment: i have implemented some complex auth system using role, module, different actions you may check here http://sqcrm.com its opensource and can download the code. This might help you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @AbhikChakraborty, I've taken a look at your system and it seems very complex. Too complex for a small simple system like mine. Therefore I would like to explore different options. I was thinking of a new method, could you please take a look at the original post after the EDIT and give me your thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned its going to be simple so this is what I can suggest you.

**At the time of login get the user id and then run a query with the id user as**

```
select 
a.au_name,a.au_id
from USER_GROUPS ag
inner join SYS_USERS su on su.id = ag.sys_users_id
inner join AUTH a on a.au_id = ag.auth_id
where ag.sys_users_id = {id of the user retrieved after the login validation}
```

**Now Execute the above query and get the `au_name` and store it in a session variable as**

```
$_SESSION['au_name'] = {auth name from the above query} ;
```

Create a function as below and execute it after the login.

```
get_page_access($au_id){
  run  a query to get all the pages for the auth id you got from previous query
  store them in an array and finally to a session variable as
  $_SESSION['page_access'] = $array ; 
  $array will hold all the pages you retrive
}
```

Now do the redirect based on the  `$_SESSION['au_name']` firstime after the login.

**Now what if user hotlink an URL i.e. a non-admin user try to access a page. So for that create a file called `check_access.php` and add include it to all the pages other than the login page.**

In this page you get the URL using PHP and get the filename from the URL, then check if that filename exists on the array `$_SESSION['page_access']` and if yes user is allowed to view the page else show message.

Make sure you do `session_start()` before the include .

This will be fairly simple in nature

Comment: Thanks @AbhikChakraborty. This seems like the best way to go for my system. One issue though, is there a more intuitive way of validating the pages? As we both have mentioned using the filename from the url (i.e. `admin_page.php`), what happens if we change the filename to say `admin_page_one.php`? We would then need to change the row in the database table `page_name` to reflect this change. I don't really see any way around this. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes thats a potential issue validating the filename, if some filename is changed then the corresponding data base entry needs to be changed also. I mean I dont see any other options for this. One better way is to use prefix for files for each different role i.e. adm_ , sales_ so just by checking the prefix you can determine who is supposed to to access the page. In this way you just need to store the prefix name in a table or even hardcode in a config file.

Comment: Thanks @AbhikChakraborty, I didn't think of that, it's very intuitive. You've been a great help! Thanks again.